# Issue with Google PageSpeed Insights - Prioritize Visible Content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-pagespeed

While developing a full-fledged website for a client, who is slightly obsessed with Google tools and suggestions, I've come across the following issue:

No matter what I do, I cannot achieve a perfect score for the homepage of the site. All other pages are 100/100 on both mobile and desktop, but the landing page gets 91 and 97 respectively - as you can see in the attached pictures.

[image: Desktop Result][image: Mobile Result]

I have tried all relevant steps I could find, including correctly structuring the HTML code and asynchronously loading everything else, plus lazy-loading the images.

A dummy representation of the code would be this:

```
html head, metatags etc
inline blocks of css (to "fix" the render-blocking issues)
the html content, in correct order with above-the-fold first
deferred js load
```

My question is, what am I missing? What else can I do to achieve the perfect score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference and anyone facing the same problem:

I've solved this issue by reducing the filesize for my homepage PHP file. This was nowhere in the guidelines or the responses around the web, but it was the thing that bumped me up to 100/100.

In my particular instance, I removed every last bit of unnecessary CSS I had included. That alone reduced the size and removed the error.

I consider the issue erroneous however, and will proceed to report this to Google - as "prioritize visible content" has nothing to do with "reduce your file size".